# Crash Report - iOS - View Controller Related?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, crash-reports

Can anyone help me understand a crash report? This is the first time I have ever had to deal with one since iOS App developing in 8 months.

I know it is something to do with dismissing a view controller that is causing it, but I have made no changes to the code regarding this but all of a sudden it is starting to cause problems. Any guidance on where to start would be amazing.

```
Date/Time:       2013-03-10 14:56:06.091 +0000
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3afee5b6 objc_msgSend + 22
1   AVFoundation                    0x3247f752 -[AVAudioPlayer(AVAudioPlayerPriv) finishedPlaying:] + 74
2   Foundation                      0x33c700f0 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 456
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3332e680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3332dee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3332ccb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3329feb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3329fd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
8   GraphicsServices                0x36e612e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
9   UIKit                           0x351b52fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
10  iWhovian                        0x000391fe main (main.m:15)
11  iWhovian                        0x0002f56c start + 36

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4e1648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b41a4ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b40cdf4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4e0eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4e1048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3332e040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3332cd9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3329feb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3329fd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x39294500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b44a30e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b44a1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4f108c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b442d2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b44cf14 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   Foundation                      0x33bec4d2 -[NSCondition wait] + 190
4   iWhovian                        0x0006ef90 -[PFCommandCache runLoop] (PFCommandCache.m:491)
5   Foundation                      0x33c6fe80 __NSThread__main__ + 968
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b44a30e _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b44a1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  AQClient
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4e0eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4e1048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3332e040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3332cd9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3329feb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3329fd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   AudioToolbox                    0x32d816fe GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 134
7   AudioToolbox                    0x32d62882 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 294
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b44a30e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b44a1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4f1d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b43fcf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b43fa12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b43f8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCConnection.m-user.com.apple.gamed
Thread 6:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3afee5b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x332b0fdc -[__NSSetI member:] + 140
2   CoreFoundation                  0x332b0f44 -[NSSet containsObject:] + 28
3   Foundation                      0x33c08978 -[NSCoder _validateAllowedClass:forKey:allowingInvocations:] + 124
4   Foundation                      0x33c08402 _decodeObjectStuff + 282
5   Foundation                      0x33c08200 -[NSXPCDecoder decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:] + 76
6   GameKit                         0x33e2f8fa -[GKInternalRepresentation initWithCoder:] + 238
7   Foundation                      0x33c086f2 _decodeObjectStuff + 1034
8   Foundation                      0x33d1fda8 -[NSXPCDecoder _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] + 532
9   Foundation                      0x33bf4ebc -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 784
10  Foundation                      0x33c086f2 _decodeObjectStuff + 1034
11  Foundation                      0x33c08200 -[NSXPCDecoder decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:] + 76
12  GameKit                         0x33e2f8fa -[GKInternalRepresentation initWithCoder:] + 238
13  Foundation                      0x33c086f2 _decodeObjectStuff + 1034
14  Foundation                      0x33c08200 -[NSXPCDecoder decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:] + 76
15  Foundation                      0x33c09fe8 _walkAndDecodeData + 1708
16  Foundation                      0x33c0988c decodeInvocationArguments + 1368
17  Foundation                      0x33c08fc8 -[NSXPCDecoder decodeInvocation] + 860
18  Foundation                      0x33c08630 _decodeObjectStuff + 840
19  Foundation                      0x33c08200 -[NSXPCDecoder decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:] + 76
20  Foundation                      0x33c07c04 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithData:] + 548
21  Foundation                      0x33d1eedc __message_handler_block_invoke_0 + 32
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b40b11c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b40a996 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 142
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b40a890 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 32
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b419212 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 190
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b4193b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
27  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b43fa0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
28  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b43f8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b4f1d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b43fcf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b43fa12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b43f8a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x208a4ef0    r1: 0x38e042ae      r2: 0x33f0ac6c      r3: 0x00000008
    r4: 0x20747372    r5: 0x2089ac70      r6: 0x33f0ac6c      r7: 0x2fdd2df8
    r8: 0x3b667530    r9: 0x0e3810ab     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x1fd4dd90
    ip: 0x3b5734ac    sp: 0x2fdd2de0      lr: 0x3247f757      pc: 0x3afee5b6
  cpsr: 0x20070030
```

Comment: Just from experience, i'd recommend restarting xcode and the simulator if you haven't yet

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into this one a while ago. The problem can be fixed by setting the `AVAudioPlayer` instance's `delegate` to `nil` in your view controller's `dealloc` method. Unless you do this, the audio player tries to make one last call to its delegate to let it know that is is done playing. But if the delegate has been deallocated, you get this crash.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    _myPlayer.delegate = nil;  // _myPlayer is your AVAudioPlayer instance
    [super dealloc]; // Only is you are not using ARC
}
```

Comment: I'm running into this issue myself, but I'm not assigning the delegate, also when I put symbolic break, the finishedPlaying gets called even if you don't set the delegate. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely trying to access an object, that hast been deallocated. Have a look at

[Debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error in Xcode using Instruments (Archived)](http://web.archive.org/web/20140108172646/http://www.ioslearner.com/debugging-exc_bad_access-error-xcode-instruments/)

to see how you can track it down.